# cannot import org.json.simple.JSONObject get error saying "org.jason cannot be resolved"

Tags: java

I'm trying to write a program that reads in a web service and phrasses it using the JSONObject object.  I'm using eclipse

when I try to import the library org.json.simple.JSONObject;
I get a error saying "org.jason cannot be resolved"

code listing

```
import java.net.URL;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
```

// Error message "the import "org.json cannot be resolved"

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection; // This is where I get the error message

public class cStart {

    cGraphData ReadData;

     public static void main (String[] args) {

               System.out.println("Welcome to the world of Java Programming.");
               String reply="";
               cGraphData ReadData= new cGraphData();
              try {
               String httpsURL = "https://bittrex.com/api/v1.1/public/getticker?market=BTC-LTC";
               URL myurl = new URL(httpsURL);
               HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection)myurl.openConnection();
               InputStream ins = con.getInputStream();
               InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ins);
               BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(isr);

               String inputLine;


               while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null)
               {
                   reply+=inputLine;
               }
              } catch (Exception e)
              {
                  System.out.println("Exception in getting data from server");
              }
              System.out.println(reply);
              JSONObject t;


}

}
```

Comment: Well, how have you put the json jarfile on your classpath?  If you have a maven project, what is the dependency you are using?  If you are building some other way, how are you including the json library?

Comment: `Note: You need to put the latest json-simple-1.1.1.jar in your CLASSPATH before compiling and running the example codes` by https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

Comment: There is no way you get `"org.jason cannot be resolved"` when importing `org.json....`. Post your real code, and the exact and complete error message. Tell us which line it refers to.

Comment: Hi the compleat error message is "The import org.json cannot be resolved" I'm using eclipse

Comment: Copy/paste the *complete* and *exact* error message into your question, including any line number info, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Just add gradle or maven dependency to your project
for gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.json', name: 'json', version: '20180130'
```

for maven

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.json</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <version>20180130</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the below dependency to your pom.xml.
It will resolve `import org.json.simple.JSONObject;`

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
    <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1</version>
</dependency>
```